# DeSerializing a List not working

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm saving a list of my class using serialization. This part works perfectly, when I try to deserialize however, it doesn't do anything.

```
private class Company : ISerializable
{
    public string Name;
    public System.IO.FileSystemWatcher Watch;
    public string Email;
}
```

The method:

```
public Company(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
    Name = (String)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
    Watch.Path = (String)info.GetValue("Watch Path", typeof(string));
    Email = (String)info.GetValue("Email address", typeof(string));
}
```

And finally the serialization itself:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(User + ".osl", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bformatter.Serialize(stream, CompanyList);
stream.Close();
```

`CompanyList` is the list holding the `Company` class objects. When I check the file it is all there perfectly. However, when I try to deserialize to the `CompanyList` it doesn't work. It goes through without an error it just doesn't give back any information.

I only just started using serialization so I'm sure I messed up something.

Edit Deserialization code:

```
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            info.AddValue("Name", Name);
            info.AddValue("Watch Path", Watch.Path);
            info.AddValue("Email address", Email);
        }
```

It looks like this. Then I just call it casting it as a List of Companies:
`(List<Company>)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);`

Comment: Please show your deserialization code.

Comment: I updated the question with the code. Sorry it took so long. :)

Comment: What if you try `object shouldBeCompany = bformatter.Deserialize(stream);` and look at `shouldBeCompany` in the debugger? What type is it?

Comment: You also haven't shown us the `CompanyList` class.

Comment: It bugs out as an exception. TargetInvocationException
Umm, there is no CompanyList class. CompanyList = List<Company>

Comment: does the TargetInvocationException have a message or inner exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the deserialization constructor throws an exception because the `FileSystemWatcher` is null.

You're setting the `Path` property of the `Watch` object, but you don't initialize the actual `Watch` object, at least not in the code you have shown here.

Comment: Agreed. In the constructor that @SaintHUN provides there is no instantiation of the filesystemwatcher. If you add `Watch = new FileSystemWatcher();` in the constructor just before the deserialization it works perfectly.

Comment: Working. Need to adjust some things but deserialization is perfect now, thank you for the help!